# cannot login to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity

I upgraded my Hp g6 from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 yesterday.

Now I cannot log into the system using Unity.

But I can still login using i3 windows manager.

I checked and found the `ubuntu-desktop` is broken. I tried to reinstall it, it complained about the dependency issue and broken package.

```
some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-desktop : Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: empathy but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

when I tried to install ubuntu-session,

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-session : Depends: gnome-session-bin (< 3.10) but
3.10.1-0ubuntu1~saucy1 is to be installed
Depends: gnome-session-common (= 3.9.90-0ubuntu12) but            
3.10.1-0ubuntu1~saucy1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

but it does not work.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Check your software sources to make sure they are "trusty" (it looks like it's trying to install "saucy" 13.10), and make sure to do a `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: My solution was to disinstall all ubuntu-desktop and gnome-session-* packages, to remove all the pre-trusty source files from /etc/apt/, update and then re-install ubuntu-desktop and gnome-session-*

Comment: thank you. I did remove other desktop session and also remove .Xauthority, and regenerated .Xauthority. It works now. Thank you all.@user2227111

Comment: @AvinashRaj  the output of apt-get install -f was fine. I remove .Xauthority and renegerate it. It works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop gnome-session-*
apt-get update
apt-get install gdm gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-session-flashback gnome-shell-extensions nautilus-share ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aptitude instead,

```
sudo aptitude install -f ubuntu-session
```

It will install ubuntu-session and dependencies with some options.